# Change display language to Arabic

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, language

how can I change the display language of the site for all users to Arabic?  I mean, I want the user interface to be for all users from right to left. I want users to see the right-to-left interface when they enter the site. As in the attached picture.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you check the regional settings in site settings?

Comment: Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-regional-settings-for-a-site-e9e189c7-16e3-45d3-a090-770be6e83c1a) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/439914/communication-site-in-arabic-tempate-not-working.html).

Comment: let me know if above suggestions work for you.

Comment: Brother, the default language of the site is Arabic, but the site appears from left to right and in English. When I change the display language from my personal account, the interface changes and becomes Arabic from right to left, but it does not appear to other users, it is the same as it is in English. How can I make the site interface appear to all users from right to left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surest way to force the use of a language is to create the site in that language.  You are prompted for the site language when you create the site
[image: Site creation dialog]

To prevent users from having a different language, the go to Site Settings / Language settings / Show advanced settings and make sure that there are no other "available languages",also called Alternate languages.

When a user visits a site, SharePoint will check the language(s) in the user's profile.  If one of them matches the alternate languages or the site's base language, that is the language that is used for the interface.  For Arabic, Hebrew, or Dari, that sets the right-to-left direction of the layout. If there is no alternate language, then displaying in other languages is not an option.

Comment: thank you very much that's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You must be signed in as a site owner or site collection administrator to choose language settings for a site. In addition, if you are using SharePoint Server, the SharePoint administrator must first deploy language packs for the languages you want to use. There is no need to install language packs for SharePoint in Microsoft 365.

1.From a site page, click Settings  Settings button from SharePoint Online, click Site Settings. If you don't see Site settings, click Site information and then click View all site settings. Some pages might require you to select Site contents, and then Site settings.

2.On the settings page, in the Site Administration section, click Language Settings.

Note: If the Language settings link doesn't appear on the Site Settings page of your SharePoint Server site or site collection, then language packs haven't been installed. See your SharePoint Server administrator.

3.Select the languages you want to make available:

- If you are using a communication site and you have page translations
  enabled, select languages by typing them or using the dropdown for
  each language. For more information on how to do this, see [Enable the
  multilingual feature for communication sites and choose languages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c#BKMK_Enable).

  If you're using a communication site without page translations
  enabled, or using a Team site or a classic site, select the check
  boxes next to the languages you want to make available.

4.If you want to [overwrite site translations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overwrite-site-translations-99f4d942-db5b-4327-82ff-9df01b6e5d88) in the site interface, select Yes under Overwrite Translations. If you're on a communication site with page translations enabled, select Advanced and then select Yes under Overwrite Translations.

5.Select OK.

Now your users can change the display language for their personal use of the user interface. Learn how users can change their preferred language in [Change your language and region settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7).

After you turn on alternate languages for your site, you can create new lists or libraries in one language, then display the site in a different language, and modify the list or library name for that language. The same process works for list and library columns, and for navigation links.

---

**If the answer is helpful, please click "**√**" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.**

Comment: thank you very much that's really helpful